# Identifying NULL results from a SUMIF Function

Tags: excel

Consider the following two excel sheets (examples only):

Sheet1:

```
Name   Marks
-------------
John   95
Alex   89
Kevin  97
John   86
Peter  99
Kevin  100
Alex   91
Peter  20
```

Sheet2

```
Name   Total Marks
-------------------
John      181
Kevin     197
Peter     119
Alex      180
Robin      0
```

**Sheet1** is the Base data and **Sheet2** is the derived data, where the Total Marks is calculated using **SUMIF** function. As seen in Sheet2, Robin has a total score of 0, as the entry for Robin is not available in the Sheet1. Is there any way where the Total Score for Robin remains as blank since there is no entry in the main sheet? I want the resultant excel to look like the following:

```
Name   Total Marks
-------------------
John      181
Kevin     197
Peter     119
Alex      180
Robin
```

Comment: If it is just an "optical" issue, you might as well just change the number format to a custom formatting, like for example `0;-0;;@`.

Comment: If you want an empty string: `IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS(...)),"")`

Comment: Is it possible to have a sum of 0 when the name is actually present and, if so, what do you want as the result?

Comment: I appreciate all of your replies my friends, but if suppose the main sheet consists of an actual 0 value for a name, I need that 0 to be shown in the final sheet instead of blank. Can you suggest a way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you check if the Name exists in the Sheet1. If not, output is blank. Else Sumif...:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9;0));"";SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9;A2;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$9=D2)*IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9;D2)>0;$B$2:$B$9;""));"")
```

It will return `0` if a candidate is found with score 0 and a `blank` if the candidate is not in the list.

This works because we generate an error when calculating `SUMPRODUCT` with blanks (which is returned by the `IF` function).

[image: SUMIF / SUMPRODUCT that shows a blank if a criteria is not in the criteria range]

Comment: You can simplify it ```=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9;D2);SUMPRODUCT((D2=$A$2:$A$9)*$B$2:$B$9);"")```